# Laravel Multiple Belongs and Relationship - Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 interconnected classes/tables. I summarised the tables for what matters

```
+--------------------+
| SelectionProcesses | 
+--------------------+
| id                 | 
| name               | 
+--------------------+
```

```
+-------------------------+
| StudentSelectionProcess | 
+-------------------------+
| id                      | 
| inscribed_student_id    | << Important
| selection_process_id    | << Important
| status                  | 
+-------------------------+
```

```
+------------------+
| InscribedStudent | 
+------------------+
| id               |
| student_id       |  << Important            
+------------------+
```

```
+---------+
| Student | 
+---------+
| id      | 
| name    | 
+---------+
```

So when I filter a selectionProcess I want get the student related by [StudentSelectionProcess -> InscribedStudent -> Student ]

I'm currently getting it, but I wanted to remove an object, my JSON:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test example name to Selection process.",
    "enrolleds": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "inscribed_student_id": 1,
            "selection_process_id": 3,
            "status": "Approved"
            "student": {
                "id": 1,
                "student_id": 1,
                "student": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Mrs. Myrtice Robel",
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test example name to Selection process.",
    "enrolleds": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "inscribed_student_id": 1,
            "selection_process_id": 3,
            "status": "Approved"
            "student": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Mrs. Myrtice Robel",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My code

```php
// SelectionProcess.php
    public function enrolleds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentSelectionProcess');
    }

    public function scopeHasEnrolleds($query)
    {
        $query->with(['enrolleds' => function($enrolledQuery) {
            $enrolledQuery->has('student')->with('student');
        }]);
    }

// StudentSelectionProcess.php
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\InscribedStudent', 'inscribed_student_id')->with('student');
    }

// InscribedStudent.php
    public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'id', 'student_id');        
    }
```

The data has been summarized, so I can't modify the model, I know there are ways to make it work, just couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SelectionProcessController.php** Controller

```php
public function showCurrent($id)
{
    $process = SelectionProcess::hasEnrolleds()->get();
    return $process;
}
```

**SelectionProcess.php** Model

```php
/**
 * This function return all enrolleds in selection process
 * 
 * @return Array StudentSelectionProcess
 */
public function enrolleds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentSelectionProcess');
}

/**
 * This function get the enrolleds only has the student 
 * 
 * @return Validation
 */
public function scopeHasEnrolleds($query)
{
    $query->with(['enrolleds' => function($enrolledQuery) {
        $enrolledQuery->has('student')->with('student');
    }]);
}
```

**StudentSelectionProcess.php** Model

```php
/**
 * This function return the student thought by inscribedStudent
 * 
 * @return Array Student
 */
public function student()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        'App\Student', // Get the student
        'App\InscribedStudent', // Through by inscribed student
        'id', 
        'id', 
        'inscribed_student_id',
        'student_id' 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just modifying the resulting json, look into [Eloquent Resources.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

You can hide unwanted data using that before sending to output.

ie.

StudentResource » individual data

StudentCollection » multiple student data

Another solution is to change your model relationship.

Since you seem to be using [intermediate tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) to connect related data. Follow the documentation and apply it on your model *so you can directly get the **Student object** without those unnecessary fields* from the intermediate table.

Also, you can use both to further improve the output according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Eloquent Has Many Deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package to add a shortcut function in order to access the `student`s of a `SelectionProcess`. You can go through [its documentation](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) to know more about how it works.

I think this setup should work:

```
class StudentSelectionProcess extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function enrolleds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            'App\InscribedStudent',
            ['App\StudentSelectionProcess'], 
            [
               'selection_process_id', // FK on the "student_selection_processes"(-ish) table.
               'id',    // FK on the "inscribed_students"(-ish) table (local key).
            ],
            [
               'id', // PK on the "student_selection_processes"(-ish) table.
               'inscribed_student_id',    // FK of the "inscribed_students"(-ish) table.
            ]
        )->with('student'); // or with('student.student'), one of them should work.
    }
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $selectionProcess = SelectionProcess::with('enrolleds')->find(3);

    return $selectionProcess;
}
```

Expected output:

> ```
> {
>     "id": 3,
>     "name": "Test example name to Selection process.",
>     "enrolleds": [
>         {
>             "id": 6,
>             "inscribed_student_id": 1,
>             "selection_process_id": 3,
>             "status": "Approved"
>             "student": {
>                 "id": 1,
>                 "name": "Mrs. Myrtice Robel",
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

---

- PS1: I'm not overriding your relationships, it's just another function.
- PS2: given that I don't have that set up to test it first, it's possible that I have a typo somewhere or messed up a key/foreign-key, but you can figure it out easily with the
  help package documentation.

Comment: Return empty: ```"enrolleds": []``` I'm trying some solutions but still unsuccessful